# Grails get by id when using relational mapping

Tags: grails, persistence

With these domain classes:

```
class Country {
    static hasMany = [states:State]
}

class State {
    static belongsTo = [country: Country]
}
```

I am unable to retrieve state by its id

```
def country = new Country()
def state = new State()
country.addToStates(state)
country.save()

def foundState = State.get(state.id)
```

foundState is null.  What is the correct way to retrieve the state from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably failing validation somewhere. Do `.save(failOnError: true)` and see if you get exception.

Also, you will not have an ID until hibernate actually does the inserts. To trigger this immediately do `.save(flush: true)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing keyword `static` and there is a typos by State (without `s` at the end), should be:

```
static hasMany = [ states:State ]
```

and

```
static belongsTo = [ country:Country ]
```

Comment: Try to save() the domain classes before you link them together, like: `new Country().save()`

Comment: Add a flag into the save method: `save( failOnError:true )`, if Grails complains about anything. I suppose, your domain class is really not empty, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

After `country.save()` call `state.refresh()` to get its latest state from the database. This is necessary because you aren't explicitly calling `state.save()` (and shouldn't need to be).